# A suggestion for reducing flag noise

Tags: discussion, flags

When someone flags a question with a close reason, that question appears on the flags page.

If someone then votes to close *for that very reason*, it **stays** on the flags page, taking up space and demanding mod attention.

1. Perhaps if the only flags are close reasons, it could live on another page, where us 10k+ types could concentrate, leaving the mods to worry about the other flags?
2. Once there's a matching close vote, why not clear the flag and let the usual close-vote-following mechanism do its job?

Answer (score 3):

> Once there's a matching close vote, why not clear the flag and let the
>   usual close-vote-following mechanism do its job?

Because uninteresting questions sometimes fail to get enough views to achieve close velocity.  This is one of the specific use-cases for mod flags: to close questions that will not otherwise get closed because they slip under the radar.

However, I would be in favor of the mod flag disappearing from the list if the post closes naturally, and the flag is a "request to close" type flag.

Comment: that already happens, fyi

Comment: How about if more than one close flag of any kind removed it from the list? That's evidence of velocity.

Comment: @Rosinante: If a question doesn't get any close votes, it generally doesn't need to be closed.  The ones that lose velocity already have two or three close votes on them.

Comment: Hmm. Well, I stand by my semi-theory: it's up to us 10k types to deal with closes (we all have plenty-o-votes), and the diamonds should be free to concentrate on using larger hammers.